# Simulating Geographic data from Longitude & Latitude in R

Tags: r, spatial, geography

I am trying to perform some simulations on models I am testing, which have both phylogenetic and geographic networks.

I wish to test the effects of these independently to compare the methods estimation abilities on each dimension. However I am having trouble generating a continuous variable that shows significant geographic spatial auto=correlation. So far I have used average yearly temperature (this is country-level data), but this does not allow me to control the size of the spatial auto-correlation. Also it has the disadvantage of not knowing the true value of spatial auto-correlation.

I have a list of Longitude and Latitude points, and I was wondering if there was a simple or common way to generate a continuous response variable that would show spatial auto-correlation, and to be able to control the size of that correlation? Preferably within R, however, as long as they can be converted to a R-compatible format, other methods would be acceptable.

Any advice would be appreciated and please ask if there is any information you would find helpful.

Comment: could you give a reproducible data snippet and show what you've tried?

Comment: Don't see any code or data here.

Comment: I didn't give any code or data because I don't think it is necessary for the question. A dataset of longitude and latitude points is all I could provide, which will not help with the problem at hand and are easily simulated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the approach in Dormann et al. (2007), you could do something like this:

```
N <- 3000
p <- 1/N

# generate some points
set.seed(1234)
x.coord <- runif(N,0,100)
y.coord <- runif(N,0,100)
points <- cbind(x.coord,y.coord)

# distance matrix between points
Dd <- as.matrix(dist(points))

# weights matrix
w <- exp(-p * Dd)
Ww <- chol(w)

# errors
z <- t(Ww) %*% rnorm(N,0,1) 

# plot
df <- data.frame(x = x.coord, y = y.coord, z = z)
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, col = z)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_colour_gradient(low="red", high="white")
```

where variable p controls the size of auto-correlation (here I set it to 1/3000 = 0.000333).
p = 0 would be no correlation.
[image]

Reference: Dormann, C. F., McPherson, J. M., Araujo, M. B., Bivand, R., Bolliger, J., Carl, G., … Wilson, R. (2007). Methods to account for spatial autocorrelation in the analysis of species distributional data: a review. Ecography, 30(5), 609–628.

Comment: Hi, Thanks - This is exactly what I am looking for. I just have a question regrading the scale of p. I was testing the level of correlation using a Moran's I test, when I set p to effectively 0 (.01) I get a pvalue of zero (as you suggested), however I get pvalue of zero up to 0.09 then at 0.095 I suddenly get a pvalue of  2.220446e-16. Do you know why this is?

Comment: variable p sets the decline of correlation with (euclidean) distance. And 2.220446e-16 ist actually 0 ;)

Comment: Sorry, I just re-read that. You should never post comments after a long night - they make you look stupid. What I meant to get across is, when using Moran's I (or some other spatial auto-correlation significance test), how can I make a non-significant result? When using Morans.I() from the ape package in R, when p = 0.0001 I still have a significant difference. Where I would have thought this would give no significant difference.